# To_date function error based on Postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```sql
Select a.*,b.event_code 
from f.table1 a join f.table2 on a.id=b.id
where a.nos='807t'
   and as_on_date=to_date (
      (select event_date from f.table2 where nos='807t'), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

If I run this I get an error:

```
Function to_date (timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist. 
Hint: no function matches the given name and argument types.   
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a timestamp to a date, use [a type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

```
Select a.*,b.event_code 
from f.table1 a join f.table2 on a.id=b.id
where a.nos='807t'
   and as_on_date = (select event_date::date 
                     from f.table2 
                     where nos='807t');
```

The syntax `event_date::date` is Postgres specific. If you want to use standard SQL, use `cast(event_date as date)`.

The function `to_date()` should be used to convert a string (varchar) value to a date value.

Note that the above query will fail if `table2.nos` is not unique!